# Google adsense not showing on localhost (WAMP)

Tags: adsense

I'm implementing google adsense on localhost using WAMP.  I'm connected to the internet but when i check chrome dev tools, i get 403 error and no ads are displayed.  I'm using localhost.  The ads should appear instantly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google_adtest = "on";
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    google_ad_slot = "2492102539";
    google_ad_width = 160;
    google_ad_height = 600;
</script>
```

I've tried asynchronous and synchronous(above) but the ads aren't showing and i get 403?  How do i solve?

Answer (score 1):

this is working with `data-ad-test="on"`

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXX"
     data-ad-test="on"
     data-ad-slot="XXX"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Comment: This has been made redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Just add google_adtest = on,

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:block"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXX"
 google_adtest = on,
 data-ad-slot="XXX"
 data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```